# Spring Boot for JPA support

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, spring-data-jpa

I found only adding properties `scanBasePackages` on `@SpringBootApplication` can not enable feature of JPA on `@Enity` and `JpaRepository`.  I have to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` and `basePackages` properties on them.  Is there any simpler solution on this? Thank you

Comment: Can you post your maven pom?

Comment: Best practice put your main class in a top level package so that Spring Boot can detect all the features you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) site, specify your 'Group' and 'Artifact' (or live default ones), in the 'Dependencies' block choose "JPA" and "H2" (or another DB you need - see 'Switch to the full version' link), then click 'Generate Project'.

In the downloaded archive you can find the Spring Boot skeleton project with JPA support.

[image]

If you look into project `pom.xml` file you can see these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 DB --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other suff -->
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add those annotations to tell Spring container you want to enable the jpa features.

You will also have to add the following depenencies in your `pom.xml` to enable `spring-data-jpa`.

```
<!-- JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Check out [this](https://github.com/Abdullah8006/myapp.git) GitHub project.